# CH376 Module with USB Floppy Drive

Tags: usb, usb-host

I'm using a CH376 module connected to a USB thumb drive and as per the datasheet, when sending the command CMD_GET_DESCR with DATA 0x01, I get 0x14 as status on interruption and then the device descriptor. Everything is working as expected with the thumb drive and I get back 18 bytes when sending CMD_RD_USB_DATA0.

But when plugging a USB floppy drive, when sending CMD_GET_DESCR with DATA 0x01, I'm always getting 0x51 back on interruption status and then all subsequent attempts to collect the descriptor data are returning 0x51.

There is no clear documentation on what the 0x51 status actually means when checking on interruption and I'm a bit lost. I was expecting the same behaviour with the USB floppy drive connected to the CH376 module.

Am I missing anything obvious?

Here is the communication with the CH376 when the USB thumb drive is connected:

```
writeCommand (CH_CMD_RESET_ALL) 0x05
writeCommand (CH_CMD_CHECK_EXIST) 0x06
writeData (0xbe)
0x41 = readData ()
writeCommand (CH_CMD_GET_IC_VER) 0x01
0x43 = readData ()
writeCommand (CH_CMD_SET_USB_MODE) 0x15
writeData (0x06)
0x51 = readData ()
writeCommand (CH_CMD_SET_USB_MODE) 0x15
writeData (0x07)
0x51 = readData ()
writeCommand (CH_CMD_SET_USB_MODE) 0x15
writeData (0x06)
0x51 = readData ()
writeCommand (UNKNOWN) 0x8b
writeData (0x25)
writeData (0xdf)
writeCommand (CH_CMD_SET_USB_ADDR) 0x13
writeData (0x00)
writeCommand (CH_CMD_GET_DESCR) 0x46
writeData (0x01)
writeCommand (CH_CMD_GET_STATUS) 0x22
0x14 = readData ()
writeCommand (CH_CMD_RD_USB_DATA0) 0x27
readDataMultiple[12]: 0x12,0x01,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x40,0x81,0x07,0x51,0x51,0x00,0x02,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x01
```

Here is the communication with the CH376 when the USB floppy is connected:

```
writeCommand (CH_CMD_RESET_ALL) 0x05
writeCommand (CH_CMD_CHECK_EXIST) 0x06
writeData (0xbe)
0x41 = readData ()
writeCommand (CH_CMD_GET_IC_VER) 0x01
0x43 = readData ()
writeCommand (CH_CMD_SET_USB_MODE) 0x15
writeData (0x06)
0x51 = readData ()
writeCommand (CH_CMD_SET_USB_MODE) 0x15
writeData (0x07)
0x51 = readData ()
writeCommand (CH_CMD_SET_USB_MODE) 0x15
writeData (0x06)
0x51 = readData ()
writeCommand (UNKNOWN) 0x8b
writeData (0x25)
writeData (0xdf)
writeCommand (CH_CMD_SET_USB_ADDR) 0x13
writeData (0x00)
writeCommand (CH_CMD_GET_DESCR) 0x46
writeData (0x01)
writeCommand (CH_CMD_GET_STATUS) 0x22
0x51 = readData ()
writeCommand (CH_CMD_RD_USB_DATA0) 0x27
readDataMultiple[51]: 0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51
```

Comment: Could you tell us which software/sources you are using? Possibly this: https://github.com/djuseeq/Ch376msc ? It looks like you can not understand the meaning of the bits in the status-data-byte, what you got back from the module. If you make your problem more clear, then you can find faster some help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MikroPower. I'm using an Arduino Pro Micro to interface with the CH376 module. At this moment I'm suspecting that the Arduino cannot provide enough power to the module and then to the USB floppy drive connected to it. I measured only 4V on the plug. The issue is that the drive doesn't have a power plug to connect an external power source so I will have to crack it open and figure out a way to provide power to it.